# Open port 80 when using HTTPS?

Tags: https, http, port, port-80, port-443

I'm going through some tutorials right now and I don't understand this one thing. Why do I have to open port 80 when I use HTTPS? Isn't port 443 enough?

Or is port 80 open to handle the redirect from http to https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to listen on http and redirect to https. But this is not mandatory.

Comment: And this will eventually change, as the browsers start to default to check the https before http when just a hostname is entered - ie, user types "google.com" in location bar, currently all check http //google.com first, eventually https //google.com will be checked first.  Until this, this answer is correct - best practice is to listen and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't mandatory. You can listen only for secure HTTPS connection on port 443.

Try to comment out the port 80 and it should work.